# Oracle SQL 11g CPU/IO performance measurements for spatial query

Tags: java, performance, oracle11g, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

How can I measure Oracle CPU utilization and IO performance?
I'm trying to establish the best connection pool size and app thread pool size for a specific spatial query in Oracle SQL 11g.
What I'm looking for is to run X queries in parallel with Y connection using Z thread and track the average/highest CPU/IO during this run.
Eventually I want determine which configuration is the most cost effective and understand how changing of the query will affects its cost and throughput in a given HW.

Any ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by 11g, you mean 11g release 2 (11.2.0.4). Anything earlier is no longer supported.

To monitor performance, you can just use the monitoring tools provided with Oracle: the standard Oracle Enterprise Manager console will give you a fairly comprehensive view of what happens. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/tdppt_realtime.htm#TDPPT033

Then you have the tools like AWR and ADDM. See the complete guide at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/toc.htm for details on how to use them.

To drive your test, I suggest you take a look at Swingbench: http://dominicgiles.com/swingbench.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've the test already developed, I just want to query for the DB performance in terms of CPU/IO, in order to make some kind of correlation to the test input for the different inputs I use. DB real time performance at the time of my test is what I'm looking for. the external tool does not help me a lot unless there is some kind of Java (or other) API, is there one? the 'MonitorDB' from your last link looks promising if I could understand how does it scrapes the data from Oracle it would be great. any clue?

Comment: All  the MonitorDB tool does is to read from the various dictionary tables/views that Oracle uses to keep statistics. Some of those are actually real-time: they are virtual tables that let you get information about the system as it operates. There are no backdoors: everything happens by querying those virtual tables and the dictionary. This is also how the enterprise manager console works. All it does is to present the information in a nice graphical way. You can find out the queries MonitorDB uses by looking at the monitored.xml file.

Comment: Thanks Albert, this was very helpful!